# Virtualbox bridge network unable to access certain ports

Tags: virtualbox

I have setup the bridge network with Virtualbox where my guest is an Ubuntu. If I run apache inside Ubuntu, I able to access it via 192.x.x.x IP from from host Windows XP.
However, if I run, a demo server such as google appengine server, which runs at port 8080, I unable access it at 192.x.x.x:8080.

- iptables is not running in Ubuntu

As I have user account only on my Windows XP, I cannot turn off firewall, but I can add expection. I added exception for incoming/outgoing port 8080, but it was of no effect. ( I think, this exception applies to service running in the computer).

I am not sure, how I can I resolve it. Any suggestions should be helpful. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are you sure that the AppEngine server is listening on all interfaces (0.0.0.0), as opposed to loopback (127.0.0.1)?

Comment: Well, thanks! I somehow overlooked that fact! :) It was indeeed the problem. I ran it to listen to all interfaces and I can access it from my host.